# How to fetch Data from the web services using NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I have made one demo code for print the data from the web Services,

## Code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://54.149.46.64/API/video.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"video" forHTTPHeaderField:@"list"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];


    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    }] resume];
```

## **Output**

```
JSON_Webservices[4496:150468] requestReply: {"Status":"Fail","Message":"Please enter required fields"}
```

Why i am not able to fetch data from the WS? Please help me.

Working Fine In Postman

## Image

[image]

Thank You.

[image]

## **header**

[image]

Comment: I think you should not set forHTTPHeaderField  for list of video. set it to HTTPBody

Comment: How to set it ? @Dheeraj

Comment: What are the parameters you're passing in POSTMan?

Comment: Easiest way to add POST data is to replace:

[request setValue:@"video" forHTTPHeaderField:@"list"];

with:

NSString *postString = @"list=video";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: @Imad Ali :- I have passed  "list" for key and "video" for value.

Comment: @user7018875 Also share the request param screenshot of the POSTMan.

Comment: @Dheeraj,@Imad Ali :-In my Mac It is showing me.Sorry Guys I am new (Freshers in Ios)let me Inform if i did mistake.Thank you

Comment: I want to see its header section. as i am not able to run it in postman

Comment: @Dheeraj:-I have added header Section Now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this...

```
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"XXXX"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = @"list=video";
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);

        NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *objectData = [requestReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                               error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", json);

    }] resume];
```

Comment: @user7018875 Just copy and past this code and check it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dheeraj,@Imad Ali For helping me